# Vim - Detect Caps Lock Status

Tags: vim, gvim, vimrc, macvim, vim-plugins

My question is simple and straightforward! =D

In this thread @OsQu...

[Vim - Is Capslock on?](https://superuser.com/questions/315701/vim-is-capslock-on)

... says that you can use the Automation Hotkey Scripting (AHK) below to detect the Caps Lock (on/off) status.

AUTOMATION HOTKEY SCRIPTING (AHK):

```
; INDICATE WHEN THE CAPS LOCK IS ON WITH A SCREEN MESSAGE
Gui, +AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow -SysMenu -Caption
Gui, Font, caf001e s30 bold ,Verdana ;changes font color, size and font
Gui, Color, af001d;changes background color
Gui +LastFound  ; Make the GUI window the last found window for use by the line below.
WinSet, TransColor,af001d
Gui, Add, Text, ,CAPS LOCK ON
; TOGGLE THE GUI ON AND OFF
~capslock::
   if(0==GetKeyState("capslock","T")){
      Gui,  hide
   }else{
      if(guilocation>0){
         guilocation=0
         Gui, Show,x600 y800 NoActivate
      }else{
         guilocation=1
         Gui, Show,x600 y400 NoActivate
      }
   }
return
```

My question is: **How can I use the AHK (Automation Hotkey Scripting) above in a function like the one that goes below in a .vimrc file?**

VIM SCRIPT (.vimrc):

```
func! CapsLockStatus()
    let l:caps_lock_status = <SOME_LOGIC_TO_CHECK_CAPS_LOCK_STATUS>
    if l:caps_lock_status == <SOME_VALUE>
        <MESSAGE_CAPS_LOCK_IS_ON>
    endif
endfunc
```

Thanks!

**NOTE:** My OS is Linux!

@Ingo Karkat